# RXcpp stream data from function continuously

Tags: c++, reactive-programming, allegro, rxcpp

I'm learning reactive for c++ and I'm looking for some guidance. I've created a function to wait for an event then return it. I want to catch all the events that occur with reactive async and handle them as they come. Here's what I have so far:

```
int Engine::Initialize()
{   
    al_init();

    display = al_create_display(1200, 800);

    eventQueue = al_create_event_queue();

    al_install_mouse();
    al_install_keyboard();

    al_register_event_source(eventQueue, al_get_keyboard_event_source());
    al_register_event_source(eventQueue, al_get_mouse_event_source());

//test: wait for 2 events to happen
    auto events = rxcpp::observable<>::create([](rxcpp::subscriber<ALLEGRO_EVENT> e) 
    {
        e.on_next(WaitForEvent);
        e.on_next(WaitForEvent);
        e.on_completed();
    });

    events.subscribe([](ALLEGRO_EVENT e)
    {
        printf("We have an Event: %d \n", e.type);
    },

    []()
    {
        printf("Done\n");
    });

    return 0;
}

ALLEGRO_EVENT Engine::WaitForEvent()
{
    ALLEGRO_EVENT event;

    al_wait_for_event(eventQueue, &event);

    return event;
}
```

I seem to get the error: *no instance of function template "rxcpp::observable::create" matches the argument list*. Do I need to make my own template or something to be able to observe an ALLEGRO_EVENT?

Answer (score 0):

From [the docs](http://reactive-extensions.github.io/RxCpp/classrxcpp_1_1observable_3_01void_00_01void_01_4.html#a68356278fbcd12847cec55bcf96a0d00), it looks like `create` uses an explicit template parameter for the return type, so you need to provide it. Your listener isn't returning anything, so `void` would work.

```
auto events = rxcpp::observable<>::create<void>(...
```

Comment: Now I get this error: no instance of function template "rxcpp::observable<void, void>::create" matches the argument list

Comment: its weird because when I paste in the sample from the docs it says the same thing

Comment: Hmm. That is weird. It might be a bug. Unfortunately, I don't have any experience using this library. I would recommend posting on their [discussion forum](http://rxcpp.codeplex.com/discussions).

Answer (score 0):

@tim had the right idea.

I am posting the answer from our [discussion](https://rxcpp.codeplex.com/discussions/656259#)

`create<>()` needs to know the type that will be passed to `on_next()`.
In addition, `WaitForEvent` is a function, but `on_next()` is expecting `ALLEGRO_EVENT` so make sure to call `WaitForEvent()` and pass the result to `on_next()`

```
auto events = rxcpp::observable<>::create<ALLEGRO_EVENT>([this](rxcpp::subscriber<ALLEGRO_EVENT> e) 
{
    e.on_next(this->WaitForEvent());
    e.on_next(this->WaitForEvent());
    e.on_completed();
});
```